# Is `python_paths` a correct parameter for pytest.ini

Tags: django, pytest

I'm working on an undocumented Django application, as a new team (all previous developper went away , so no help is available)
The pytest.ini looks like this :

```
[pytest]
python_paths = my_app
```

According to [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath), there is no `python_paths` option, only `pythonpath`.

The tests are working fine by now, and I don't know what to do :

1. Keep that option, it may somehow be used
2. Rename to `pythonpath`, like it should always has been
3. Delete, as it is unused anyway (I tested, it works fine without)

**I know StackOverflow isn't meant for opinions, I'll try to find a lead dev at my company for that. I'm just looking for confirmation that i'm not missing an usage**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is probably using the plugin [`pytest-pythonpath`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pythonpath/). If you use pytest 7.0.0 or greater, then it is completely safe to rename to `pythonpath`, as they do the same thing; in fact, you *should* switch to the built-in option as it's better than relying on a plugin.